# my query not work for datetime help me please

Tags: android

i want to get last 1 week record from database using current date but my query wil not getting any result from database help me i try so much  see screen shot

[image]

date which store in database is in "datetime" format and date which i used current date 1 week old date is in string format  what is problem please help me

```
  value save in database in this format  " 19/02/2014   14:08"
   jobarr = db.getALLCompJobs(sCurrent,sWeekBefore);



        private static final String TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS = "jobs";


    private static final String KEY_COMPID = "_compid";
private static final String KEY_TIMEJOB = "timejob";
private static final String KEY_TIMEWEEK = "timeweek";

private static final String KEY_PICK = "pick";
private static final String KEY_DEST = "dest";
private static final String KEY_FARE = "fare";

        String CREATE_COMPLETED_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS
            + "(" + KEY_COMPID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TIMEJOB
            + " TEXT,"   + KEY_PICK + " TEXT," + KEY_DEST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FARE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIMEWEEK + " datetime" + ")";



        public List<JobSchmeModel> getALLCompJobs(String sCurrent,String sWeekBefore) {
    List<JobSchmeModel> compjobsList = new ArrayList<JobSchmeModel>();


        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " WHERE " 
+ KEY_TIMEWEEK + ">=" + sWeekBefore + " AND " + KEY_TIMEWEEK + "<=" + sCurrent + " 
 ORDER BY "+KEY_COMPID+" DESC";

     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    when i see in debug query look like this

  SELECT  * FROM jobs WHERE timeweek>=19/02/2014   09:17 AND timeweek<=26/02/2014   
 09:17 ORDER BY _compid DESC
```

Comment: if that you'r query you should change it to:   SELECT  * FROM jobs WHERE timeweek>='19/02/2014   09:17' AND timeweek<='26/02/2014   
 09:17' ORDER BY _compid DESC

Comment: but date save in my database is this format  19/02/2014   14:08 three space in between date and time

Comment: u mean add colon  around date like this timeweek>='19/02/2014   09:17'

Comment: SQLite DateTime format is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" (see [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html))

Comment: yes , you can try run the query on you'r client till it work.

Comment: but server sent me datetime in this format dd/MM/yyyy   HH:mm
when i check in debug value is like this   19/02/2014   14:08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote your literals here:

```
SELECT  * FROM jobs WHERE timeweek>=19/02/2014   09:17 AND timeweek<=26/02/2014
```

like this

```
SELECT  * FROM jobs WHERE timeweek>='19/02/2014   09:17' AND timeweek<='26/02/2014'
```

This will fix the *syntax*. However, it will use lexicographic (alphabetical) ordering and not chronological ordering as the data is really just strings, not datetime stamps.

To make it behave the way you want, you need to change the stored data so that the ordering matches chronological ordering. For example, use

1. Unix timestamps (seconds since epoch) or Java timestamps (milliseconds since epoch)
2. ISO 8601 stamps like YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:MM

Probably the most straightforward way is to *parse* the dates returned by the server using a   `SimpleDateFormat` and store the Java millisecond timestamp in database.

Comment: i did my query show in debug like this 

SELECT  * FROM jobs WHERE timeweek>='19/02/2014   10:01' AND timeweek<='26/02/2014   10:01'  ORDER BY _compid DESC

Comment: but timeweek datatype is  Datetime  and dates are string

Comment: To sqlite they are just strings.

Comment: u mean change this like + KEY_TIMEWEEK + " DateTime" + "  to  + KEY_TIMEWEEK + " Date" + "

Comment: help me this query work fine
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " WHERE " + KEY_TIMEWEEK + ">='19/02/2014   14:08' AND " + KEY_TIMEWEEK + "<='29/02/2014   14:08' ";

Comment: i give hardcoded date but when i give dates using system is not give any result help me

Comment: As suggested, use milliseconds in the database and convert to/from datetime strings in code.

Comment: String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " WHERE " + KEY_TIMEWEEK + ">='19/02/2014 14:08' AND " + KEY_TIMEWEEK + "<='29/02/2014 14:08' "; it will work fine but if i give variable is not work tell me why